# Modify the display Text of number of comments

Tags: customization

How can i modify the text of number of comments to custom text.

My current display is like this

[image]

I want it to be displayed like this.

[image]

My `commpents.php` is

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments.
 *
 * The area of the page that contains both current comments
 * and the comment form.
 *
 */

/*
 * If the current post is protected by a password and
 * the visitor has not yet entered the password we will
 * return early without loading the comments.
 */
if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php

                printf( _nx( 'One comment:', '%1$s Reviews:', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'simone' ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() )
                                );
            ?>
        </h2>

        <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'style'      => 'ol',
                    'short_ping' => true,
                                        'avatar_size'=> 50,
                ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .comment-list -->
        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="comment-navigation clear" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'simone' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( sprintf( '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left">%s</i> ', __( 'Older Comments', 'simone' ) ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( sprintf( '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right">%s</i> ', __( 'Newer Comments', 'simone' ) ) ); ?></div>
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
        <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php
        // If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
        if ( ! comments_open() && '0' != get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'simone' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php comment_form(); ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```

Comment: You'll need to modify the `comments.php` file..

Comment: Is there no way to write a plugin instead

Comment: That is generally hardcoded in the `comments.php` file. However, you can replace that with a `do_action();` hook, then that can be used to print whatever you like using functions.

Comment: could you please give me a fully written function

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full `comments.php` code, then I might help you out.

Comment: what i mean is using the do_action() hook

Comment: i have updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the

```
<?php
        printf( _nx( 'One comment:', '%1$s Reviews:', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'simone' ),
           number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() )
                 );
?>
```

with

```
<?php 
    do_action('my_comments_title_hook');
?>
```

And then ( since the function `comments_template()` is called within the loop, you can simply ignore the post type check using `$post->ID` ):

```
function change_coments_title() {

    if ( get_post_type() == 'post' ) {
        printf( _nx( 'One comment:', '%1$s Comments:', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'simone' ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) );
    } elseif ( get_post_type() == 'review' ) {
        printf( _nx( 'One Review:', '%1$s Reviews:', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'simone' ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) );
    } elseif ( get_post_type() == 'page' ) {
        printf( _nx( 'One Review:', '%1$s Reviews:', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'simone' ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) );
    }
    //Other post types
}
add_action( 'my_comments_title_hook', 'change_coments_title' );
```

The example function above doesn't change anything for 'posts', but if you are on a CPT called 'reviews', it will do the trick. Do let me know if you want to chenage the title for all post types.

Comment: it is not working ...... i have a doubt over `my_comments_title_hook`

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan, it should work, let me know what post type you are on.

Comment: I am on page....the page name is review

Comment: Okay, edited my answer to change the comments title for 'page' post type. DO let me know if that works.

Comment: Glad to know that.

Comment: Isint it possible without hardcoding `comment.php`....by using `preg_replace()` by attaching to `comment_form_after` and `comment_form_before` hooks?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The comments template is depended on the theme and in most cases called by `comments_template();`, which looks for the `comments.php` file in theme root. You can override it by setting the location of your custom comments template, like `comments_template( '/custom-template.php' );` Either way, you have to modify the theme for what you want to achieve.